# Suggestion needed to avoid table scan in large view w/many duplicate values

Tags: db2

Could anyone offer a solution to speed up one of our processes?  We have a view used for reporting that is a union all of 10 tables.  The view has 180 million rows.  We would like to generate a list of the distinct values of individual columns.  The current SQL generated by the reporting tool does a select distinct on the view which takes 10 minutes.  Preferably the solution would be automatically updated.  We have been trying to create a MQT in DB2 udb V8 as a union all, refresh immediate with little success.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Charles.

Comment: can you create a materialized view of the distinct list?

Comment: Materialized view is the Oracle term for a DB2 Materialized Query Table.  When I try to do the select distinct and refresh immediate I get this error: "When REFRESH IMMEDIATE is specified, the fullselect must not contain: 
o   SELECT DISTINCT "  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of restrictions in DB2 8.2 for refresh immediate MQTs, and they can have a significant performance impact on applications that write to the base tables.  That said, you *may* be able to use an MQT.  However, instead of using SELECT DISTINCT, try making the query look something like:

```
select yourcolumn, count(*) as ignore
from union_all_view
group by yourcolumn
```

The column (yourcolumn) from must be defined as NOT NULL for this to work (in DB2 8.2). The optimizer may not select this MQT if you still issue SELECT DISTINCT against the union all view, so you may need to query the MQT (or a view defined on top of it) directly.  Ignore the column "ignore" in the MQT -- that is there only for DB2;  if you really don't want to see it, you can create a vew on top of the MQT.

However, this is really a database design issue.  Why do you need to scan 180 million rows of data to find the unique values in a particular column?  Why don't these values already reside in their own table, with foreign keys defined against it from each of the 10 base tables?